# SerializerMethodField not showing up - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

So im trying to add a new field to my serializer by using SerializerMethodField(), but it is not showing. How come?

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) ##
    content = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.author.username

    def __int__(self):
        return self.id
```

serializers.py:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def get_username(self, obj):
       return obj.username
       #return obj.author.username dooesnt work either
```

view.py where i go to see the details of a post;

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def postDetail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = PostSerializer(post, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and this is what turns up, username field is missing:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "content": "6",
    "date_posted": "08/12/2020 18:33:55",
    "author": 1
}
```

Comment: What if you set `fields = ['username']` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu the fields remain untouched, same result as my last code block. Im printing it out from my views & going to the api url

Comment: Which means, Django/Python is not using the same serializer class that you are making the updates. That is, If you set `fields = ['username']` in your serializer's `Meta`, DRF will never show other fields ***at any cost***